# How to add language switcher in popup on loading Magento2 homepage for first time

Tags: magento2, modal-popup, language-switcher

I am creating a website with 2 store views - `English` and `Arabic`.
I would like to add the `language switcher` inside a `popup` when a user opens the homepage.

But the popup need to display only once (probably by setting some cookie value or whichever is efficient).

For example, If I add the `modal popup` in a widget and call it in homepage, is there a way to limit the number of occurrences? Or Could anybody please help me with a better idea on how to do this. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a cookie when showing the modal, then each time you show it, check if the cookie is already present and don't show it in that case. Just make sure to not set the cookie and then check if it is set, otherwise you would never see the modal.

The flow could be something like this:

1. Check if the cookie is present
2. Show the modal if not
3. Set the cookie if it was not present

You should be able to do most of this in a custom phtml template and the cookie handling in a custom block.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But s there any better way to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid no, the cookie is the best option. You need to somehow recognize the user, the easiest and most reliable way to do that is with a cookie. (You could also use local storage, but that's basically the same)